# Check if two functions are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, wronskian, linear-independence

I have to check if $f(s)=s,~g(s)=e^{ks},~k\in\mathbb{C}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

The wronskian is $W[s,e^{ks}]=e^{ks}(ks-1)$. Then, if we take $s=1,~k=1+0i$, it becomes $0$ and hence, it is not linearly independent.

Is my reasoning correct?

Edit: thank you all. My error was that the Wronskian is used when those functions are solutions for a differential equation, and I don't have that hypothesis.

Comment: Late comment, but since this question popped up again: functions are linearly independent if their wronskian is not identically zero. The logic in the post was wrong (the wronskian being zero at a single point implies neither dependence or independence, and we shouldn't get to choose $k$) but the idea of using the wronskian works fine. For example, $s = 2/k$ yields a wronskian of $e^2 \neq 0$ so the wronskian doesn't vanish identically so the functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what Wronskian is but here is a way to show that $f, g$ is linearly independent.

Proof: Suppose that $f, g$ is linearly dependent. Without loss of generality, suppose that $g=a_1f$ for some non-zero $a_1\in R$. Then differentiating both sides twice we see that the left hand side is non-zero and the right hand side is zero. We get a contradiction and thus $f, g$ is linearly independent.

Edit: For the case of $k=0$, we can differentiate both sides once and get a contradiction as the right hand side would be equal to $a_1$ and $a_1\ne 0$.

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wronskian.html

Comment: Thank you! This is a great way to solve it. I was trying to use the Wronskian since that is the tool i'm learning to use.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín You're welcome! I should point out that I skipped the step where $k= 0$. In which case, we can differentiate once and get a contradiction. I will add that to the post.

Comment: However, using my method, I found a value for $k$ and $s$ where the wronskian is zero. If the wronskian is zero then the functions are not linearly independent. That is confusing me :/

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín I will be of no help regarding the Wronskian as I am not too familiar with it. But maybe wait around and someone will answer that. Or ask a new question regarding that.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín The Wronskian must be identically zero for linear dependence. Not sometimes zero.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín The Wronskian is a function of $s$. The function as a whole must be the zero function. It's not sufficient for the function to have roots.

Answer (score 4):

$k$ is fixed and you don't get to choose it. Don't you have the result that if the Wronskian is *nonzero* for *some* value of $s$, then the functions must be linearly independent? After all, if they are linearly dependent, then the Wronskian will be zero for all values of $s$. In your case, the Wronskian will be zero for at most one value of $s$ (if $k$ happens to be nonzero and real).